# MooTools Fx.SmoothScroll for internal links not working on my site

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, anchor

I'm working on a project that I wish to have smooth scrolling on. I've taken a look at all available documentation from mootools.net and [this post from David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-fx-smoothscroll) on the topic. Copy-pasting code doesn't seem to work, and the only difference that I see is the version of MooTools used(1.4.5 here)—and the function name seems to be the same as 1.2. Chrome 23 throws the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" but I can't find an error in Firebug. Doesn't scroll properly in Firefox either.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready',function() {
        new Fx.SmoothScroll({
            duration: 200
        },window);
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href='#one'>One</a>
<h3 id="one">One</h3>
</body>
```

I'm also relatively new to JavaScript as well, so if you could explain the process, it'd help a lot! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've gotten it to work in this jsFiddle. Perhaps this will give you a clue as to what is going on? http://jsfiddle.net/6NNBV/

**Update**:

To have it load on page load, try this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    new Fx.SmoothScroll();
});
```

**Edit**: Disregard below:

I believe page anchors do not work on the `id` of the target element, but rather, the `name` property.

Try adding a `name` property to the `h3` element.

Comment: Great! If I remove MooTools more the script doesn't work. I see that it's set to work 'onLoad'. How do I wrap my code in HTML to do that? I've tried `window.onload = new Fx.SmoothScroll();` to no avail.
Edit: This code is no longer in the <head> element.

Comment: That's correct, Fx.SmoothScroll is a Mootools More feature, so it is required to function. See my updated answer, not sure why `window.onload` wouldn't work...

Comment: Thank you! Solved. What I changed was moving the code from head to body and adding MooTools More. Probably More is what did it. Don't know how I missed that.